# How to pass in order id or any custom id for tracking purposes?

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I am using vue and this npm library https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-checkout

Let's say I want to store the record into db, and I would like to have an id which I can correlate to my user id or order id in my db. I don't know how to pass in any custom id inside the "render" function block.

Here's my relevant code block for paypal button:

```
paypal.Button.render({
  env: 'sandbox',
  client: {
    sandbox: 'yyyyyyy',
    production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
  },
  commit: true,

  payment: function (data, actions) {

    return actions.payment.create({
      payment: {
        transactions: [
          {
            amount: {
              total: '1.00',
              currency: 'USD'
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      experience: {
        input_fields: {
          no_shipping: 1
        }
      }
    })
  },
  onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
    console.log('onAuthorize:' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))

    // Get the payment details
    return actions.payment.get()
      .then(function (paymentDetails) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(paymentDetails, null, 2))
      })
  },
}, '#paypal-button-container');
```

And here's the *paymentDetails* I received:

```
{
  "id": "PAYID-L55D0123998RG7601237",
  "intent": "sale",
  "state": "created",
  "cart": "35W055448123",
  "create_time": "2020-08-04T07:08:12Z",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "VERIFIED",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "sb-123@personal.example.com",
      "first_name": "John",
      "middle_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "payer_id": "XXXX",
      "country_code": "US"
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "1.00",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "related_resources": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use that? It's PayPal's old client-side SDK and the old v1 payments API.  There is a newer checkout SDK, as well as a new v2 checkout API.  Here's the UI code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and on the server side: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ , maybe you can find a vue module

Comment: Yea, I wanna use the v2 api, however when I use the npm package and import it with `import paypal from 'paypal-checkout'`, `paypal.Buttons()` will throw error.

Comment: not sure which npm package that is or what error you're speaking of